# Best way to release production code

Tags: php, version-control, compilation, release, revert

Is there a best practice for releasing production code for PHP?

I know with Java you can release the source code as a WAR or JAR but does PHP have something like this?

As our org grows I wanted to find a better way of releasing production code instead of the current process with is not acceptable.

Current Process:

- Check New Code into SVN (Subversion)
- Make backup of current production script and append it with .bak.date_time_stamp
- Move new script into production (FTP, SSH, SFTP)

Need the ability to

- revert changes
- optional container (think JAR)
- archive current production code
- automate? this is a wish list option

Any other suggestions/options/practices that would be good to incorporate? Looking at changing the org process.

Comment: By "release", do you mean for distribution, or use in your system?

Comment: @Jonah use in our system. Didn't think about distribution but that's also something to consider

Comment: Doesn't SVN provide everything you ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rough equivalent to War or Jar would be [Phar](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php). There is a tutorial by Cal Evans at

- http://blog.calevans.com/2009/07/19/lessons-in-phar/

Won't go into other Deployment strategies, because those have been discussed before:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deployment+strategies+php

Comment: Does the Phar container have any issues that are common when using/running with Apache? Also to note we are running PHP 5.2.x

Comment: @Phill I've never used it, but IIRC its somewhat slower than unpacked PHP. Not sure if that applies when using a Bytecode cache though. I think there is a PECL package for no longer supported PHP versions, aka PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [phar](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) as a PHP alternative to jar/war; and at tools like [phing](http://phing.info/trac/) for building/deploying releases (it's a PHP variant of ant)

Comment: Phing is based on Apache Ant. I found Ant, incredibly useful (and extensible) when working with Java, but I never used Maven. I've only recently started using Phing... but it feels very familiar and easy, and seems to provide the same levels of power and flexibility for building deployment scripts. I've not pushed it yet, and am looking forward to really putting it through its paces, but I'm very satisfied so far.